# HTML/JSON: Translate placeholder depending on locale

Tags: html, json, locale, translation

I have a JSON file with translations. I specifically have an attribute called `Select_Time_Format`. I want to use this translation in a placeholder attribute for an HTML field (seen below)

```
      <label for="time-format" i18ng="'Time_Format'"></label>
      <div class="select2-container select x100" id="s2id4">
        <select ngyn-select2
                ng-model="$ctrl.tournament.time_format"
                ng-options="key as label for (key, label) in $ctrl.timeFormats"
                id="time-format"
                name="time_format"
                class="select x100"
                placeholder="Select Time Format">
        </select>
```

Is there some way to replace `placeholder="Select Time Format` with something like `i18ng="'Select_Time_Format'"`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the proper syntax is as follows.

`placeholder="{{ 'Whatever_Your_Translation_Name_Is' | t }}"`